# How to replace all newline characters except the ones after " using php regex

Tags: php, regex, string

Please help me with a regular expression to replace the newline characters with dot (.) in the following dummy lines.

First line where i want to replace the newline character
Second line where i want to replace the newline character
I want to skip this line as i have quote at the end "
Third line I want to replace new line character

**Expected**
First line where i want to replace the newline character.Second line where i want to replace the newline character.I want to skip this line as it has quote at the end "Third line I want to replace new line character

Comment: You want to make all/most of the text single line? Replacing a newline removes the formatting. Are you sure you don't want to just insert a dot before the newline? What if it already has a dot there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(?<!")(\R|\z)/', '.', $input);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fP3mC3/5)

- `\R` matches any Unicode newline sequence.
- `\z` assert position at the very end of the string.
- `(?<!")` is negative lookbehind to make sure line end is not preceded with `"`

Comment: How do `\z` and `$` differ?

Comment: `$` will match EOL for each line in a multiline input in mode `m`. However `\z` only matches once at the end of input.